# Magento always SSL url showing all on pages

Tags: magento, ssl

I have a Magento site, i have ssl on it, there is huge problem with that
when i enable the ssl using backed it shows ssl urls in every page in my site with product pages. i just disable ssl from admin panel and clear all cashes and sessions, but it still showing https urls on back end and font end every pages.

after i disabled the secure urls from the back end now when i click on save config button it gives js warning

```
Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?
```

when click on yes it gives a message successfully saved but nothing saved at all,
so now no matter what ssl disabled all pages showing SSL
can anyone help me please

Site url is
http://panoramicessentials.com [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that SSL is not forced by apache config or in .htaccess with mod_rewrite rules. Also check if your unsecure_base_url is http:// not https://

Comment: yes the problem was with .htaccess  it force rewrited all urls